# How many times can you chain a single Intent object with putExtra()?

Tags: android, android-intent

My question is essentially if the value that is in the intent object, when sent through a second time, does it have the same values again, and if so, is there a limit to how many times this can be done?

Comment: sent through a second time means .....?

Comment: Sorry about that. Like when it finishes up and gets to onActivityResult() and using it again and send it to another Activity to the same activity used in the startActivityForResult()

Comment: No problem @Andy, Intent.putExtra() keeps your VALUE until you clear Application Data....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we talk about Intent then it is used to **Perform any Operation**.

e.g `intent.putExtra(key1,value);`

All depends on the `value`. If your value is not null then you can use it as many times you want. It has no Limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any number of times `intent.putExtra(key,value);`
but you have to make sure that the value and the key is not null and key is different from previous used keys.